# download AOSP UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: download, android-source

I try to download AOSP following https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.

In the repo sync step,I get an error

***File "/Users/fish/WORKING_DIRECTORY/.repo/repo/git_refs.py", line 155, in _ReadLoose1
    ref_id = ref_id.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
Fetching projects:  99% (452/456)*

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors**

Is there anybody meet the same problem?how should i do?
I use Mac 10.10.5

Comment: I found the same issue on linux, have you got any resolution for it?

Comment: @SandeepDhull I did not solve the problem.I dont remeber it clearly, you could try sync again or delete the code then sync again.

Comment: ok, i think it has something to do with the development environment, i should learn python first

Comment: My python version is 2.7.10,and now everything is ok.I hope it can help you